# JQuery pass a variable from function to function

Tags: jquery, function, parameter-passing

I have a variable that is retrieved via a .click function and I want to pass it to another function but I"m having trouble passing it correctly because when I call the other function nothing happens.

```
var className;
var flavor;
(function ($) {

  Drupal.myTest = Drupal.myTest|| {};

  Drupal.behaviors.myTest= {

    attach: function (context, settings) {

          Drupal.myTest.myFunction= function (className) {
            var passedVar= className;
            alert(passedVar);
          };



          $('.buttons').on('click', function(event) {
            className = $(this).attr('class');
          });

          $('#test').on('click, function(event) {
        Drupal.myTest.myFunction();
          });

    }

  };

}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
(function ($) {
    var className;
    var flavor;

    Drupal.myTest = Drupal.myTest|| {};

    Drupal.behaviors.myTest = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
            Drupal.myTest.myFunction= function (className) {
                var passedVar= className;
                alert(passedVar);
            };

            $('.buttons').on('click', function(event) {
                className = $(this).attr('class');
            });

            $('#test').on('click', function(event) {
                Drupal.myTest.myFunction(className);
            });
        }
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work.  Could you please see my edit to my question above and you may be able to get a better representation of my code?

Comment: @CR47 you need to pass `className` as a parameter in the call `Drupal.myTest.myFunction(className);`

Comment: @CR47 that is a parameter definition... not there... where you call that function... in this case inside `$('#test').on('click', function(event) {
    Drupal.myTest.myFunction(className);
});`

Comment: @CR47 @CR47 in your case `myFunction` is accepting a parameter with name `className` so in the scope of the function className will refer the local parameter not the closure variable `className`

Comment: @CR47 I've updated the answer with your new code... another solution is to remove the parameter `className` from `myFunction` so that inside the function scope `className` will refer to the closure variable

Answer (score 0):

Declare the function outside of `$(document).ready()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myPassedVar;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.buttons).click(function() {
          var className = $(this).attr(class);
        });

        myFunction = function (className) {
          myPassedVar = className;
          alert(myPassedVar);
        };

        $('#test').click(function() {
          myFunction(className);
        }
    }); //END $(document).ready()
</script>
```

Comment: Did you mean declare the variable?

Comment: OUTSIDE of document ready. Declare it, create it, assign it a value, just make sure it exists outside $(document).ready() -- or its shorthand version: $(function()

Comment: I made an edit to my question that shows my code better in addition to the suggestion you made.